# How can I automate a simple website search?

Tags: scripting, automation

There's a lot of scripting and programming I want to learn in the future, but for now, I just would like to make this script that seems like it should be very simple.  I've searched and there are so many options and tutorials for very powerful tools, that seem to require prerequisite knowledge that I would also have to learn.  I would just like the simplest/quickest method that I can use to help me automate the following:

I have hundreds of links leading to a website search on an Excel spreadsheet.  Most of the links will lead to a page that says the same "No results found."  Some of the pages will have different results I would like to save so I could look at them myself.  How can I automate this so I don't have to click and check each link manually, without spamming the website?  Here's a task list I have but I have no idea how or where to begin implementing this.  Thanks for any help.

1. Open tab
2. Open link
3. Wait for loading
4. Check page if worth saving new results  (? I have no idea how this is possible)
5. Save page/record results
6. Mark link complete
7. Close tab
8. Move to next link
9. Wait
10. Repeat x 100 or so

Comment: This is far too broad a topic; what language do you plan to use, for a start? Personally, I'd export the Excel to TXT/CSV then [use Python to interact with each URL](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/).

Comment: This question is too broad. If you don't have any programming experience you should look for a tool that has record an play, or if you don't need UI you can try with a performance testing tool.